# why does priority queue constructor take capacity with comparator?

Tags: java, constructor, priority-queue

Why does priorityQueue in java force user to input an initial capacity when it asks for comparator ?

```
PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity, Comparator<? super E> comparator) ?
```

Why cannot it have a constructor with single argument called

```
 PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator) ?
```

Comment: Note Java 8 will have such a constructor: http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a hard-and-fast reason for this.  There's no *fundamental* reason why you can't do this - it would be trivial to add by just doing this:

```
public PriorityQueue(`Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this(/* reasonable default */, comparator);
}
```

My guess is that it was an oversight in the design.  As @Sotirios Delimanolis pointed out in the comment, in Java 8 this constructor will be added.

Hope this helps!